# What is the standard for tagging Docker images?

Tags: docker

Is there a agreed-upon or official style for tagging Docker images?

i.e a docker style of Semantic Versioning http://semver.org/

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, Docker is too new and changing a bit often for there to be an established convention or standard, apart from using the "latest" tag for well, the latest.